# win32evtlogutil error in Python3

Tags: windows, python-3.x, error-handling, event-log

To write to windows event log I have the scripts below:

```
....
win32evtlogutil.ReportEvent(
    "TEST001",
    101,
    eventType=0,
    data = err_log_path + 'error_TEST001.log'
)
...
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

What should I do?

Comment: It looks like you actually want `strings=[err_log_path + 'error_TEST001.log']` as a parameter instead of using the binary `data` parameter.

Comment: Consult the PyWin32.chm file docs for `win32evtlog.ReportEvent`. The convenience function `win32evtlogutil.ReportEvent` is basically the same, except it handles registering the event source via `hAppLog = win32evtlog.RegisterEventSource(None, appName)` before reporting the event, and subsequently calling `win32evtlog.DeregisterEventSource(hAppLog)`.